# Alternative to iframe for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

So I'm currently using `iframe` to embed Bing Translator and also Bing Images onto my website. However, I want to find alternative to iframe because I'm using a certain library that can't detect `iframe`. What alternatives can I use to embed website onto my ReactJS app?

A little more details:
The library that I'm using is `OpenReplay` which is an open-source session replay library. However, on its website, it is mentioned:

> If your web app includes iframes, then you won't be able to playback their content as part of your recordings. You can still start OpenReplay inside an iframe by including tracker.start(), but it will considered as a separate tab, which means it will be captured in a separate recording.

Having a separate tab is definitely not something I want.

Answer (score 0):

I can feel the pain of using iframes in today's world. There are a few legacy sites and a few standard modules which are not available as open source, in that situation alone we can go for iframes.
since you mentioned 'Bing Translator' I believe Microsoft has an API available for that purpose checkout [MS Translator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/translator-api/)  and guide for a free setup [translator setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/how-to-create-translator-resource) alternatively you can go with other platforms too.